# Converting an array with only one object in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Say I have an array, and I use the `keep_if` or `select` methods to delete everything but one object for the array -- is there a way to take that object out of the array, so it's not an array any more?

For example, the way my models are set up, `previous` and `current` will only ever have one object.

```
 def more_or_less?(project, current_day)
    words = project.words
    current = words.select {|w| w.wrote_on == current_day}
    previous = words.select {|w| w.wrote_on == (current_day - 1.day)}
 end
```

So, if I want to do a comparison, like `if current.quantity > previous.quantity` -- I've resorted to actually writing if `current.last.quantity > previous.last.quantity` but I'm assuming there's a more idiomatic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're deleting all but one entries, why not use [`find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001484) to choose the one thing you care about? Something like this:

```
def more_or_less?(project, current_day)
  words    = project.words
  current  = words.find { |w| w.wrote_on == current_day }
  previous = words.find { |w| w.wrote_on == (current_day - 1.day) }
  if current.quantity > previous.quantity
    #...
  end
end
```

If you're in ActiveRecord land, then you can use [`detect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001485) as derp says or `to_a` to get a plain array that you can use `find` on:

```
def more_or_less?(project, current_day)
  words    = project.words
  current  = words.detect    { |w| w.wrote_on == current_day }
  previous = words.to_a.find { |w| w.wrote_on == (current_day - 1.day) }
  if current.quantity > previous.quantity
    #...
  end
end
```

Comment: No, that's what I was looking for. Why didn't occur to me that find would work, I don't know.

Comment: Actually -- I'm in a Rails project, so when I use `find` it's looking for a primary key.

Comment: What is `words` then? Is it a single ActiveRecord object?

Comment: words is an array (project has_many => :words), that's why I'm selecting out of it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

detect is an alias for find, maybe that would work